# Implementing AJAX and database operations with Wicket

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, wicket

I'm trying to add AJAX to my project.

I have a link and a boolean variable named `hasEngagement` in my Wicket page. I want my link to produce a JavaScript informational warning if the boolean value is true, or perform a database operation otherwise. Here's my code:

```
Link myLink = new Link("mylink"){
     @Override
     onSubmit(){
     if(hasEngagement)
        //ajax operation
     else
        // database operation
     }
};
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an AjaxLink: http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/AjaxLink.html

And override onClick

cheers

Lee

Answer (score 0):

Also you can assign your message to a Feedback message. And of course use AjaxLink

Answer (score 0):

```
AjaxLink myLink = new AjaxLink("mylink") {
     @Override
     public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
     if (hasEngagement) {
        target.appendJavascript("alert('information warning');");
     } else {
        // database operation
     }
};
```